# Как изменить расстояние между строчками TextView?

Tags: android

Всем привет! Есть обычный textview с большим текстом. Как можно изменить расстояние между строчками. Альтернатива в css line-height:.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lineSpacingExtra` или `lineSpacingMultiplier` в xml.

Comment: Спасибо помогли!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:lineHeight="35dp"
```

Мне так помогло в XML.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/746347)